# Get children of Dom_html.element

Tags: dom, ocaml, js-of-ocaml

In js_of_ocaml, is it possible to get the child nodes of [`Dom_html.element`](https://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/dev/api/Dom_html.element-c)?

I know that the class inherits [`Dom.node`](https://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/dev/api/Dom.node-c), and thus has the `childNodes` method. But since it is a method from `Dom.node`, it returns values of `Dom.node` types. And I need those nodes to still be `Dom_html.element`, or else most methods will not be available.

Since downcasting is not possible in OCaml, I do not find any possible solution for this issue. Am I missing something or is this really impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`childNodes` cant't be typed as a collection of `Dom_html.element`s because the nodes returned can, and are likely to, include nodes that are not `element`s, such as text nodes.

The DOM standard defines a property `children` on `Element` which would only return the elements, but that still wouldn't get you to `Dom_html.element`. And unfortunately it also does not seem to be included in JSOO's `Dom.element`.

You can use the `element` function of [`Dom.CoerceTo`](https://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/dev/api/Dom.CoerceTo) to safely coerce `Dom.node`s to `Dom.element`s, but I don't think there is any generally reliable way to go from `Dom.element` to `Dom_html.element`, because the DOM is unfortunately too dynamically typed.

You might have to check the `tagName` manually and (unsafely) cast it using `Js.Unsafe.coerce`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Since the elements I am working with are div, I used: `Js.Opt.bind (Dom.CoerceTo.element node) (fun elem -> if (Js.to_string elem##.tagName) <> "DIV" then Js.Opt.empty else Js.Opt.return (Js.Unsafe.coerce elem))`